# Why does `(count nil)` return 0?

Tags: clojure, null

In Clojure, I find this surprising:

```
> (count nil)
0
```

I would expect a type error, as in this case:

```
> (count 77)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: count not supported on this type: Long
```

since `nil` is not a list:

```
> (list? nil)
false
```

Does `nil` have a special status as an empty sequence?

Answer (score 5):

From the official [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count):

`count`:

> Returns the number of items in the collection. (count nil) returns
>   0.  Also works on strings, arrays, and Java Collections and Maps

So this is the spec ;)

I imagine that it ensures that any mutating value having a "countable" type  can be handled at runtime.
Indeed, any reference, referencing an allowed type (strings, arrays, and Java Collections and Maps) might target `nil` at some point.

Comment: You're right, and the docs for `first` and `rest` also call this out as a special case. This seems inconsistent with both Lisp and Java to me. Is there some situation where this would be handy?

Comment: This behavior is not particularly inconsistent with (Common) Lisp--as Thumbnail's answer indicates.  In CL `nil` = `()` = logical false (and there is no other logical false).

Answer (score 5):

there is a old lisp tradition to conflate nil and the empty list.

Now Clojure doesn't adhere to that one but in the LISP differences pages

http://clojure.org/lisps

you can read

> A big difference in Clojure, is sequences. Sequences are not specific
>   collections, esp. they are not necessarily concrete lists. When you
>   ask an empty collection for a sequence of its elements (by calling
>   seq) it returns nil, saying "I can't produce one". When you ask a
>   sequence on its last element for the rest it returns another logical
>   sequence. You can only tell if that sequence is empty by calling seq
>   on it in turn. This enables sequences and the sequence protocol to be
>   lazy.

Thus to be able to chain "seq" calls with many other traditional processing functions (first, rest etc.) you have to deal with nil as some kind of an empty list (this is just my understanding of the whole affair).

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: `(seq ()) => nil`, `(seq []) => nil` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure has an abstraction first design (these abstractions can be protocols, interfaces, or multimethods). That is to say, that a function shouldn't generally target a specific datatype, but rather it should operate on some abstraction type, and let any datatype implement that abstraction in order to be used by that function.

Functions in Clojure that work on ordered collections should target `clojure.lang.ISeq`. The complication here is that we want to also target native types like `String` or `Array` or `List`, where we cannot add a supertype retroactively. Our solution is to use `seq` to get an instance of `clojure.lang.ISeq`. It turns out that it is convenient to treat `nil` as an empty `ISeq`, this simplifies eg. various linked list representations, as it's natural to have a `nil` next element for for the last element of the list, and thus to treat `nil` as an empty list.

Comment: So in short, Clojure does use nil-punning, but not in Clojure lists; only in the Sequence abstraction. Right?

Answer (score 2):

*Does `nil` have a special status as an empty sequence?*

Yes. This is called *nil-punning* - a Lisp tradition, as [Freakhill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28934647/1562315) says.

In Clojure, it only works in one direction:

- If you supply `nil` where a sequence is expected, it turns itself
  into the empty sequence. This works in general, not just for `count`.

For example,

```
(concat nil) ; => ()

(map inc nil) ; => ()
```

- But if you supply an empty sequence where `nil` might be expected,
  for example, as a logical false value, it does *not* convert to `nil`.

For example

```
(if () 1 2) ; => 1

(if nil 1 2) ; => 2
```

[This page](https://clojure.org/lazy) explains how Clojure, by departing from the traditional Lisp model, is able to better exploit lazy sequences.